# Why does java.util.zip.CRC32.getValue() return a long, not an int?

Tags: long-integer, crc32

See the title. The returned value is 32 bits, right? Why not return an int?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Because if it returned an int, half of the CRC's would be negative.  The expectation is that a 32-bit CRC is unsigned, i.e. 0..4294967295, which cannot be represented in an int.

Comment: Mark, thanks for the answer. I have a follow-up: I am reading and writing files whose last bytes are a CRC of all the preceding bytes. The the CRC must fit in 4 bytes. So I cannot just ignore the upper 4 bytes of the long CRC, can I?  I would need to convert the long to an "unsigned" represention first right?

Comment: By definition, a 32-bit CRC fits in the low four bytes of the long.  There is no unsigned 32-bit type in Java.

Comment: The fact that the Java language does not support unsigned integer types is irrelevant here. Signed or unsigned any 32-bit value can be stored within a Java int, which is 32-bits in size.

Comment: @bughouse26 Yet, that is why.

Answer (score 10):

[`java.util.zip.CRC32`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/zip/CRC32.html) implements the [`Checksum`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/zip/Checksum.html) interface, which requires a `long` return type for `getValue()`, therefore requiring a `long` for a 32-bit checksum; the upper 32 bits of the output are almost definitely 0.